# Change order of models in a ggplot (dotwhisker)

Tags: r, ggplot2

To my knowledge, there are many threads that deal with the order of legends or factors in ggplot. However, I failed to find advises how to change the order of multiple models within a single plot. The dotwhisker-package by Solt & Hu integrates ggplot for their plots.

```
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + disp + gear, data = mtcars)
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . + hp) 
m3 <- update(m2, . ~ . + am)

threeM <- rbind(tidy(m1) %>% mutate(model = "M1"), 
                tidy(m2) %>% mutate(model = "M2"), 
                tidy(m3) %>% mutate(model = "M3"))

dwplot(threeM) +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
          panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="grey"))
```

The plot looks like this:
[image: https://imgur.com/JkUcy7t]

The problem with this plot is that the coefficients and CIs of model 3, which should be the last presented values, are presented first in each row.

I want the coefficients in each row to be presented chronologically. That is, M1 coefficients+CI above M2 coefficients+CI. And M2 coefficients+CI above M3 coefficients+CI. More plainly: The red line should be above the green line, which should be above the blue line.

The use of the models as factor hasn't proven useful.

```
threeM$model <- factor (threeM$model, levels = c("M1","M2","M3"), labels = c("M1","M2","M3"))
```

Do you have any idea how I could display the models in a chronological order in each row? I hope you understand what I mean and I thank you in advance.

*Note: I adapted examples from here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dotwhisker/vignettes/dotwhisker-vignette.html.*

Comment: Ugh, the `dwplot` function has hard coded the line `df[[model_name]] <- factor(dfmod, levels = unique(dfmod))` which relevels your factors. Basically you have no control over it with the existing function. You can create your own version, or try to hack the resulting ggplot object.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
threeM <- bind_rows(
tidy(m1) %>% mutate(model = "M1"), 
tidy(m2) %>% mutate(model = "M2"), 
tidy(m3) %>% mutate(model = "M3")) %>% arrange(desc(model))

threeM$model <- factor (threeM$model, 
levels = c("M1","M2","M3"), 
labels = c("M1","M2","M3"))

dwplot(threeM) +
theme(legend.title=element_blank(), 
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="grey")) +
scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1",
breaks=c("M1","M2","M3"))
```

Explanation:

The models on the plot are sorted from bottom to top. I changed this by sorting them in descending order and making sure their factor levels are sorted that way: `%>% arrange(desc(model)) threeM$model <- factor (threeM$model)` The models on the legend are sorted from top to bottom. This can be changed defining breaks: `scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1", breaks=c("M1","M2","M3"))`

Comment: Could you add an explanation for *why* and *how* it works?

Comment: My guess the models on the plot are sorted from bottom to top. I changed this by sorting them descending order and making sure their factor levels are sorted that way: 
 
    %>% arrange(desc(model))
    threeM$model <- factor (threeM$model)

The models on the legend are sorted from top to bottom. This can be changed defining breaks:

   scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1", breaks=c("M1","M2","M3"))

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty of editing your explanation into your answer, comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Good point.  The solution I hit on when Hu [recently noticed the issue](https://github.com/fsolt/dcpo_dem_mood/blob/bf4c1fb8a109d13c8504ecedb3e3ae71774aa9ca/paper/dcpo_demsupport.Rmd#L637) in our own work was to use the `guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)` argument to `scale_color`:

```
threeM <- bind_rows(
tidy(m1) %>% mutate(model = "M1"), 
tidy(m2) %>% mutate(model = "M2"), 
tidy(m3) %>% mutate(model = "M3")) %>%
arrange(desc(model))

dwplot(threeM) +
scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1",
guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="grey"))
```

[image: dwplot with models ordered correctly]

[We'll work on getting this fixed, though.](https://github.com/fsolt/dotwhisker/issues/98)